# Laravel storing many to many relationship via eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I realise a lot of people have probably had somewhat of the same problem, but I just want to clarify some things up for myself and hopefully others.

I have 3 tables: `categories`, `subcategories` and `category_subcategory`. In the models I define the relationship like this:

```
// Category class

public function subcategories()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Subcategory::class);
}
```

---

```
// Subcategory class

public function categories()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Category::class);
}
```

Now when inserting the data in the link table I'm using this:

```
$category = new Category();
$category->name = $categoryData['name'];
$category->subcategories()->sync($categoryData['subcategoryIds']);
$category->save();
```

I get back this error:

`` SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'category_id' cannot be null (SQL: insert into `category_subcategory` (`category_id`, `subcategory_id`) values (?, 3,5)) ``

So the question is, if I'm not doing anything else wrong, how do I insert the `category_id` of the current record that I'm creating?

Comment: Move `$category->subcategories()->sync($categoryData['subcategoryIds']);` after `$category->save();`. You're trying to `sync()` for a Category that doesn't exist yet.

Comment: because the `Category` instance you created doesn't exist (it is a new instance, it does not represent a record in the database atm) so it has no ID since it hasn't been saved yet